# Type 'Observable<...> is not assignable to type Observable<HttpResponse<...>> due to missing properties

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

In my Angular 8 app I have the following interface:

```
export interface MyStructureResponse {
    content?: MyStructure[];
    page?: number;
    size?: number;
    totalElements?: number;
    totalPages?: number;
    last?: boolean;
}
```

I want to add error handling, so in `api.service.ts` I added:

```
private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(error);
      this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

      return of(result as T);
    };
  }

  private log(message: string) {
    console.log(message);
  }
}
```

and also I had a working function:

```
getMyStructure(): Observable<HttpResponse<MyStructureResponse>> {
    return this.http.get< MyStructureResponse >(
        localUrl, { observe: 'response' });
  }
```

that I modified by adding:

```
getMyStructure(): Observable<HttpResponse< MyStructureResponse >> {
    return this.http.get< MyStructureResponse >(
        localUrl).pipe(retry(3), catchError(this.handleError< MyStructureResponse >('getMyStructure', {})));
  }
```

however, after this modification, the last method throws an error:

```
TS2322: Type 'Observable< MyStructureResponse >' is not assignable to type
'Observable<HttpResponse< MyStructureResponse >>'.   
Type 'MyStructureResponse' is missing the following properties from type 
'HttpResponse< MyStructureResponse >': body, type, clone, headers, and 4 more.
```

I cannot figure out how to fix it.

Comment: You deleted the argument to get that changed the response type, setting the option observe to "response". It's unclear why you removed it if you *didn't* want to return an observable of MyStructureResponse.

Comment: when I added it back, I'm getting an error: `Type 'Observable< MyStructureResponse | HttpResponse< MyStructureResponse >>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpResponse< MyStructureResponse >>'.
      Type 'ShelterResponse | HttpResponse< MyStructureResponse >' is not assignable to type 'HttpResponse< MyStructureResponse >'.
        Type 'MyStructureResponse' is missing the following properties from type 'HttpResponse< MyStructureResponse >': body, type, clone, headers, and 4 more.`

Comment: `getMyStructure()` is expecting a return type `Observable<HttpResponse< MyStructureResponse >>` but you are returning `Observable< MyStructureResponse >`

Comment: Because catchError doesn't return a type consistent with what the get would return otherwise. Either correct the function signature and discriminate the types downstream, or be consistent.

Comment: `catchError` comes from package `rxjs/operators` and I cannot change it, so I need to somehow fix my code, could you please help me with that and post it as an answer to accept? Thanks, I've been struggling with it for more than an hour now :|

Comment: Sorry, it's handleError that has the wrong return type, that's what make catchError and the function overall wrong.

Comment: could you please paste it as an answer with a draft of a solution? thank you!